# How do I send a bad request if request body is incorrect using mongoose and express

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const appointmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

const officeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    office: [appointmentSchema]
});

const Offices = mongoose.model('Offices', officeSchema);

module.exports = { Offices };
```

server.js

```
app.post('/offices/:id', (req, res) => {
    // Add code here
    const id = req.params.id

    const appointment = {
        name: req.body.name
    }

    Offices.findById(id).then((office => {
        if (!office) {
            res.status(404).send('Not found')
        } else {
            office.waitlist.push(appointment)
            office.save()

        }
    }))
        .catch((error) => {
            res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error') 
        })


})
```

Hello, I am just trying to figure out how to make sure a bad request isn't being sent. "office" is the office schemia is a list of appointmentSchema. In the route in server.js it will find the id of some office and insert an appointment at the end of the waitlist. The issue is if I send for example

```
{

    "abc": 24

}
```

then it would still push this into office but it will ignore the "Abc". I don't want this being pushed at all. i.e. office will be

"office: [{_id: "someid"}]"

I want it to detect its bad input and return status 400

Comment: If the intent is to check that a `name` property should exists on `req.body`, then validate it with JS before the `appointment` object creation ex: `if( !req.body.hasOwnProperty('name') ){ return  res.status(400).send('Bad request'); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do request data validation in different places:

## 1. Validate in controller using Celebrate

Celebrate is a validation middleware for express using Joi, to install, run `npm i celebrate`

Then use it in your app, example:

```js
const { celebrate, Joi, errors, Segments } = require('celebrate');

app.post("offices/:id", celebrate({
    [Segments.BODY]: Joi.object().keys({
        name: Joi.string().required()
}),(req, res) => {
    
    // req.body.name now isn't empty
    // do something with it

});
```

If celebrate middleware found an incorrect data, it will thrown to your [express error handler](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

## 2. Validate in service / business layer using Joi

This is pretty similar with the first option, but you are doing the data validation in your *business layer*

First install Joi with `npm i joi`

Then you can create a schema for your validation and use it, for example:

```js
const Joi = require('joi');


const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().required()
});

app.post("offices/:id", (req, res) => {
    
    const validatationResult = schema.validate(req.body); 

    if (validatationResult.error) {
        // error found
        console.log(validatationResult.error);
        return res.status(400).send();
    }

    // do something with req.body.name

});
```

You can do many other stuff with Joi like specifying min / max length, match regex pattern, etc. You can check the doc [here](https://hapi.dev/module/joi/) (You can also do similar checking with celebrate since celebrate also use Joi)

## 3. Validate in Model

You can do data checking in mongoose model using [Mongoose Validations](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) as suggested by @jcragun

---

I personally prefer to put the data validation on service / business layer or model because it makes more sense.

You can also check [joigoose](https://github.com/yoitsro/joigoose) which allows you to do Joi validation in mongoose schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Mongoose validations](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html). You can require fields and ensure they're the right type. You can also create your own custom validators.

For example:

```
const appointmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```